# Jqgrid Date Search not Working

Tags: jqgrid

I have a date field in Jqgrid.

It works fine with the Other data (text data) search options but when i try to search the date field it does not works.

Comment: Can you add the jqgrid code..

Comment: Solved by adding this  sorttype: "date" and search: true